# Select only 1 payment from a table with customers with multiple payments

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called "payments" where I store all the payments of my costumers and I need to do a select to calculate the non-payment rate in a given month.

The costumers can have multiples payments in that month, but I should count him only once: 1 if any of the payments is done and 0 if any of the payment was made.
Example:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| ID |  DATEDUE   | AMOUNT |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2016-11-01 | 0      |
|  1 | 2016-11-15 | 20.00  |
|  2 | 2016-11-10 | 0      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

The result I expect is from the rate of november:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| ID |  DATEDUE   | AMOUNT |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 | 2016-11-15 | 20.00  |
|  2 | 2016-11-10 | 0      |
+----+------------+--------+
```

So the rate will be 50%.

But if the select is:

```
SELECT * FROM payment WHERE DATEDUE BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-30'
```

It will return me 3 rows and the rate will be 66%, witch is wrong. Ideas?

PS: This is a simpler example of the real table. The real query have a lot of columns, subselects, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to partition your results per customer.

```
SELECT        TOP 1 WITH TIES

              ID,
              DATEDUE,
              AMOUNT

ORDER BY      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC)

WHERE DATEDUE BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-30'
```

PS: The BETWEEN operator is frowned upon by some people.  For clarity it might be better to avoid it:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT
    id
    , SUM(AMOUNT) AS AMOUNT
FROM
    Payment
GROUP BY
    id;
```

This might help if you want other columns.

```
WITH cte (
    SELECT
        id
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY AMOUNT DESC ) AS RowNum
        -- other row
)
SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    RowNum = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry I did not mention, my example is a simple one. The table is huge and my select have a lot of columns, subselects, etc. I cant use group.
Anyway, will not solve the problem of the example, as I need the DATEDUE too in the results.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the rate, you can use explicit division:

```
select 1 - count(distinct case when amount > 0 then id end) / count(*)
from payment
where . . .;
```

Or, in a way that is perhaps easier to follow:

```
select avg(flag * 1.0)
from (select id, (case when max(amount) > 0 then 0 else 1 end) as flag
      from payment
      where . . .
      group by id
     ) i
```